# reduce the loop iteration if condition does not meet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.status.length; i++) {
    if(data.status[i].isMode == 0) {
        var row = '<tr><td>' + data.status[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data.status[i].Pay + '</td></tr>';
        var row = '<tr><td>' + data.status[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data.status[i].Pay + '</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

it works smooth, but if there are 5 items as of `data.status.length` and `2` items has value of `isMode` as `0` and other as 1, it still loops `5` times and displays those values,i just want to hide those values and because they are used for amount calculation, i don not want their values too to be the total

This is my JSON

```
{
  "status": [
    {
      "Name": "Apple",
      "Pay": "1",
      "isMode": "0"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Banana",
      "Pay": "1",
      "isMode": "0"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Kiwi",
      "Pay": "1",
      "isMode": "1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Fruits",
      "Pay": "1",
      "isMode": "1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Basket",
      "Pay": "1",
      "isMode": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please share an attempt at solving the problem as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and include it as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to your question.

Comment: My guess is that 'isMode' is set to a wrong value somewhere. Please show the code that sets this property.

Comment: BTW: Why do you have 2 lines of code with exactly the same code?

Comment: i added the json i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter your array of objects according to isMode property then loop with the result

```
var newArray =data.status.filter(function (el) {
    return el.isMode==0;
}
for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    var row = '<tr><td>' + newArray[i].Name + '</td><td>' + newArray[i].Pay + '</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop looping once you find a match for the `isMode == 0` condition, use the `break` statement

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.status.length; i++) {
    if(data.status[i].isMode == 0) {
        var row = '<tr><td>' + data.status[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data.status[i].Pay + '</td></tr>';
        break;
    }
}
```

You can also use the `find` method:

```
var found = data.status.find(s => s.isMode == 0);
if (found) {
    var row = '<tr><td>' + found.Name + '</td><td>' + found.Pay + '</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Print your statuses inside.

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < data.status.length; i++) {
     if(data.status[i].isMode == 0) {
       document.write('<tr><td>' + data.status[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data.status[i].Pay + '</td></tr>');
     }
   }
   ```
2. Filter modes outside and print.

   ```
   data = data.status.filter(e => e.isMode == 0)

   for (var i = 0; i < data.status.length; i++) {
     var row = '<tr><td>' + data.status[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data.status[i].Pay + '</td></tr>';
   }
   ```